# Autofac OnRelease() not being called

Tags: autofac

I have a class, Foo, which is used to configure the container and functions as a factory for another class, Bar, which is used as the entry point for a windows service.

The Bar class is injected with an instance of Baz which opens a socket connection.

In Foo, an IBaz is configured with an OnActivated() to open the connection and an OnRelease() to close the connection.

An acceptance test uses Foo to create Bar and validates some expected results.  The problem is that the test never completes because the Baz connection is never getting closed.  This is due to OnRelease() never being called.

My understanding is that once Foo goes out of scope and is garbage collected, the container should invoke the OnRelease() delegate.

Why might this not be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a lifetime scope to control the releasing of components. Lifetime management in Autofac is always explicit, and doesn't rely on GC.

In this case it may be the container itself that plays this role- disposing the container would cause `OnRelease` methods to be called. It is a bit of a long read but [this](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer) covers the details.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this.  I don't recall the details now, but I think OnRelease() wasn't being called because the socket was keeping the object alive.